# Multi-targeting project raises The target "_GetRestoreSettingsPerFramework" does not exist

Tags: win-universal-app, build-error, multitargeting, moniker, dotnet-sdk

I'm trying to update one of my existing C# project to the new Microsoft.NET.Sdk project structure. The solution consists of net45, netstandard1.0 and uap10.0 projects.

- When I run "**dotnet build ValueConverters.sln**" from the NuGet Package Manager Console, I receive following error:
  error MSB4057: The target "_GetRestoreSettingsPerFramework" does not exist in the project.
- When I build the same ValueConverters.sln solution in Visual Studio using MSBUILD, everything works fine.

The solution can be found here:
https://github.com/thomasgalliker/ValueConverters.NET/tree/develop

What am I doing wrong? When I remove uap10.0 from the TargetFrameworks, it works like a charm.

Comment: I could build successfully in my side.  only different is `<NuGetToolVersion Condition=" '$(NuGetToolVersion)' == '' ">4.8.1</NuGetToolVersion>` in ValueConverter.uwp file.

Comment: Did you run "dotnet build ValueConverters.sln" from the NuGet Package Manager Console? That's how I run into the error.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the above comment.

Comment: Why do you want to use dotnet build, I could build the solution with msbuild and vsbuild success, I could not sure dotnet support all your project.

Comment: Adding the NuGetToolVersion to the uwp10.0 PropertyGroup did not work. I spent so much time already to support building an UWP library using dotnet build and still it shows the MSB4057: The target "_GetRestoreSettingsPerFramework" does not exist in the project.